# 1. Use cell value to find value in range, 2. copy it & 3 cells to the right then 3. paste it in another range 4. loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I've been creeping this forum for ages but haven't yet commented as normally the questions have been asked and answered! I'm a complete newbie so my code will look awful.

The title is the basis of what I want to do. Other questions have allowed me to figure out the first 3. points but I'm unable to loop it.

1. Cell E4:E (last row with data in) is the value I am using to find
2. In N4:N (Last row with data in). Once found, select and copy that cell and the next three cells to the right.
3. Paste these in H:K (last row with data in).
4. Loop back to 1. but lower the row by 1 i.e. E5 and continue 2. & 3. until there is no data in the row of E:E.

   ```
   Sub Copy_cells()

   ' Copy_cells Macro

   Dim FindString As String
   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim Rng1 As Range
   Dim lastrow As Long

   FindString = ActiveSheet.Range("E4").Value
   lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("H65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

   If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
       With ActiveSheet.Range("N:N")
           Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                           After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                           MatchCase:=False)


           If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
               Application.Goto Rng, True
               ActiveCell.Resize(1, 4).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("H" & lastrow)


           Else
               MsgBox "Nothing found"

   End If
   End With
   End If

   End Sub`
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub test()

Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim lastrow As Long


lastrow_E = ActiveSheet.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row 'Set last row of E
First_E = 2 'First row in E
ActiveSheet.Range("$E$" & First_E & ":$E$" & lastrow_E).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo 'Remove duplicates from E

lastrow_E = ActiveSheet.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row 'reSet last row of E

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("H65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Set last row of H
lastrow_checker = lastrow

lastrow_N = ActiveSheet.Range("N65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Set last row of N

For Each c In Range("E" & First_E & ":E" & lastrow_E) 'loop E
    Found = 0
    FindString = ActiveSheet.Range(c.Address).Value 'Set findstring
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then 'make sure not blank
        For Each cell In Range("N1:N" & lastrow_N) 'loop N
            If cell.Value = FindString Then 'if cell = findstring
                Found_H = 0
                For Each ce In Range("H1:H" & lastrow) 'loop H if found
                    If ce.Value = FindString Then 'search for findstring in current list
                        Found_H = 1 'found set variable
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If Found_H = 0 Then 'if not found put it in
                    Range(cell.Address).Resize(1, 4).Copy Destination:=Range("H" & lastrow) 'resize, copy and paste
                    lastrow = lastrow + 1 'Increment lastrow for next value
                    Found = 1
                End If
                Found_H = 0
            End If
        Next
        If Found = 0 Then
            lastrow = lastrow + 1 'leave a blank row
        End If
    End If
Next

If lastrow = lastrow_checker Then
    MsgBox "Nothing Found"
End If
End Sub
```

This should get you on your way to be able to build your code

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seems to search for every occurance of the value in E4, it then copies and pastes them in the correct format in the last row of H:K.

However, I would like it to find the first occurance of the value in E4, then do the rest of what your code says, then loop back for the value of E5 until it reaches the last filled in row of E.

Comment: I have added a loop for col E in my code above. May need to adjust "E1" to start of your data.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being extremely dumb and thank you for the response! I have changed adjusted E1 to the start of my data but it comes up with the message "Nothing Found" everytime the code is executed.

Comment: The problem was that findstring was always blank the first time around so If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then would never be true. I have moved the code around so that findstring is set each time. I have revised the code above

Comment: Incredible work!!! 2 Slight changes.

1. If the value in E is in multiple times in colum N it copies and pastes all of the occurances. I would like it to just paste the first occurance if possible.

2. If the amount isn't found it moves on to the next row in Column E but still pastes it in the current row for H:K. it would be great if it also misses that row in H:K.

Apart from that it works perfectly, can't believe you fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: 1. I have a fix for. 2. Im not sure what you mean? do you want it leave a blank row in H:K? or just leave the current value in E in H?

Comment: Excellent!! Yes, if it could leave a blank row in H:K that would be perfect!

Comment: You're a genius. 2. works perfectly but 1. still copies duplicates unfortunately instead of the first occurance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on duplicates? in which column would be handy?

Comment: There are a multiples of the same value in N. The current formula copies and pastes all lines with that value one after the other into H:K. it would be great if, instead, it only copies the first occurance and then ignores the others.

Comment: My bad, I overwrote some code. Thanks StackOverflow for revisions ;). above should be there now

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code and stuck in the loop I think you're after, plus a couple of minor changes.

```
Sub Copy_cells()
' Copy_cells Macro

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim startrow As Long
    Dim intCount As Long

    startrow = 4
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("H65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For intCount = startrow To lastrow

        FindString = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & intCount).Value

        If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
            With ActiveSheet.Range("N:N")
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)

                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Application.Goto Rng, True
                    ActiveCell.Resize(1, 4).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("H" & lastrow)
                    'I'm not quite sure where you want to paste this back to??
                    'lastrow doesn't seem correct.. maybe use intCount?

                    'also this code probably works but could probably be rewritten as:
                    'Rng.Resize(1, 4).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("H" & lastrow)
                Else
                    MsgBox "Nothing found"
                End If

            End With
        End If
    Next intCount

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I wish I could upload a screenshot to imgur to show you the screen I'm using but imgur is blocked at work.

This code doesn't seem to work for me. It seems to display the Nothing Found error and then continue to paste a row that isn't always the next one down.

I.e. The values in E range go from 100 - 500 in 100 increments, it should copy the relevant data from N:Q that matches, so 100 - 500 in increments. Instead it copies 100, 300, 200, 500 etc.

Comment: sorry, I'm very confused about what the end result is. I didn't really change your code except to loop it through cells in column E. Try stepping through the code (press F8) line by line to understand what's going on and debug it.

Comment: It was me being dumb! OK this code works great!!! There is only one problem and one thing that can be improved :)

- If it could cycle throughout the entire list, copying and pasting until finished instead of having to execute the code for each line that would be increadible!

- When the amount can't be found it brings up the "Nothing Found" error and then falls over by either copying and pasting the line after that twice or by bringing back nothing. I would like it to leave that row blank and then cycle onto the next row. 

I am being extra difficult sorry.